# A term for a spot, placement or location in the sky?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, terminology

When I say *location*, it's intuitively implied that I refer to a place on the Earth's surface. What would be a good term for the position in the sky?

> When I'm at this *location* I see the sun at/on/in that *xxx*.

It's not *angle* because there are two angles. And it's not *angles* because I'm looking for a term for such spot. It's not *direction* because I'm referring to a *point in the spherical shell*.

I hope for something technical, scientific and really hairy. I'm thinking in terms of *azimuth* not *direction* and *elevation* instead of *slope*. You get the style.

Comment: How about _locus_? However, [position](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun) itself is a pretty good choice of word.

Comment: Astronomers refer to the _apparent position_ of a celestial body (always, of course, relative to another one!) because there is, by definition, no fixed point of reference in the entire cosmos.

Comment: @Yuri Post it as a reply, please.

Comment: But if you already know *azimuth* and *elevation*, and you're hoping for "something technical, scientific, and really hairy", why not just use those?  (Or *right ascension* and *declination*, if you prefer those.)

Comment: There cannot be a "position" in the sky because "the sky" is a linguistic construct and not a physical one. There is no "sky" in which to occupy a position! This is why astronomers use the phrase _apparent position._ This is like asking Parmedides to show us a picture of what is described by the word _nothing._

Comment: @Konrad Viltersten I suggest you post your question [here](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com). You might get more accurate responses.

Comment: @stangdon Because I'm looking for **a single term** for those. Imagine that we know *latitude* and *longitude*. The corresponding term would be *location*. Imagine we have *Saturday* and *Sunday*. The corresponding term would be *weekend*. Do you see what I'm aiming at?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I know it doesn't sound very hairy or technical, but _apparent position_ really is the common technical term here. An observer on Mars would use the same term, but with Mars as the fixed point of reference.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I disagree that it's a relevant statement. Drawing pictures of something is not equivalent to having a term for it. We can't draw a picture of *impossibility*, *paradox*, *dark hole*, *anger*, *invisibility* etc. yet we have terms for those concepts. I believe that *(apparent) position* will do.

Comment: Not just _position._ In every glossary of terms, _apparent position_ or _place_ is the usual term. Every astronomer, amateur or professional, uses this term. Sometimes, perhaps to sound a tad more learned, folks use the Latin for position, which is _locus._  :)

Comment: You don't know what is for this in Swedish to look it up in the dictionary, do you?

Comment: @KonradViltersten It is far afield from astronomy, but you might find Pamenides of Elea interesting.

Comment: @Rompey Not exactly, no. I'd go with something like *himlavalvsläge* if you twist my arm bu tit's far from optimal. Possibly *belysningshåll* but that's not great neither. And hard to translate so it doesn't get lost in translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the word [*position*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun) itself is a good choice of word that can fit in your sentence.

> When I'm at this location I see the sun in that position.

[*Solar position*](http://naturalfrequency.com/wiki/solar-position) also might work for you although considering using *sun* in your sentence, it might be redundancy since it basically means the *sun's position*.

However you might want to look up *locus* that I found in one of the answers given [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/what-is-the-shape-of-the-suns-orbit-around-the-earth-taking-into-account-ellipt).

(*I'm not an astronomer obviously and I post it as an English learner. I hope you find it useful.*)

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no physical "sky" in which to occupy a position, astronomers use the terms [**apparent place**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_place) and [**apparent position**](https://www.google.com/search?q=astronomy%20%22apparent%20position%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to describe a "position in the sky." Note that the word *apparent* is very important in conveying the meaning of the term: it does not describe a true physical position (which cannot exist) but the position *as it appears to the observer.*

OED defines *apparent* as:

> **6.** Appearing to the senses or mind, as distinct from (though not necessarily opposed to) what really *is*; seeming. Contrasted with *real.*

Thus, an astronomer would say:

> When I'm at this location I see the sun in that *apparent place/position.*

The [*International Astronomical Center's*](http://www.icoproject.org/glos.html) glossary defines *apparent place* as:

> **Apparent place:** the position on a celestial sphere, centered at the Earth, determined by removing from the directly observed position of a celestial body the effects that depend on the topocentric location of the observer: i.e., refraction, diurnal aberration (see aberration, diurnal) and geocentric (diurnal) parallax. Thus the position at which the object would actually be seen from the center of the Earth, displaced by planetary aberration (except the diurnal part - see aberration, planetary; aberration, diurnal) and referred to the true equator and equinox.

For a demonstration of the term "in the wild", see [*astronomy.stackexchange.com.*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22apparent%20position%22)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the expression: ***[astronomical position](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/astronomical+position):***

> - A point on the earth whose coordinates have been determined as a result of observation of celestial bodies. Also known as astronomical station.
> - A point on the earth defined in terms of astronomical latitude and longitude.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of Scientific & Technical Terms)

Comment: OP is hoping for a term to use in reference to a position _in the sky,_ which by definition cannot exist.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - that's why, as explained in the answer, an  astronomical position is a point that refers to coordinates on the earth. Please read!